# Start instagram? Start on instagram?

Tags: prepositions

I heard someone saying 
"Just started instagram"

And

"Just started on instagram"

Or

"Just started my Instagram"

Which ones correct??

Answer (score 5):

They are all commonly used, and acceptable in everyday conversation.

However, the most formal way to say that would be:

> Just started using Instagram.

"Instagram" is a company, which provides an eponymous service or application that a person can sign up for and use.

The first version you listed, "Just started instagram", is the most clunky and could be misinterpreted to mean

> I'm an entrepreneur, and I just created a company named 'Instagram'

or

> I'm a software operations engineer, and I just initialized the server and software environment to support the application named 'Instagram'

Which are obviously not what this person meant.  If they turn 'instagram' into a verb, and said "Just started instagramming", then what they meant would be clear.

The third version you listed, "Just started my instagram", is best interpreted as "I just opened my account with Instagram", or "I just created my first post on Instagram".  They are conflating their account to use the service ('my instagram') with the service itself.